# OrientDB shortestpath - specific edges

Tags: graph, orientdb, shortest-path

I have a Question about the shortestPath() Function of OrientDB.

I confirmed that the following functions are valid.

> select shortestPath('#9:1', '#15:1', 'BOTH','Friends').

However, in the above method, only 'Friends' can narrow down.
For example, you want to do it with 'Friends' and 'Family'.

> select shortestPath('#9:1', '#15:1', 'BOTH',['Friends', 'Family']).

But it did not go well. Is it impossible to acquire the shortest path by specifying multiple edges?

Comment: Right now it's not supported, but it's not hard to do. Could you please open an issue here https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues I'll manage it as soon as I can

Comment: Just added a little fix, now it works fine.